# Count how many times document.hasFocus returns "true", if it's equal or greater than 15 do something

Tags: javascript

I'm using `setInterval` to check every second for `document.hasFocus()`, so every second it returns `true` or `false`.

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(document.hasFocus());
}, 1000);
```

When the return of `true` is equal to or greater than 15, I would like to do something. I wrote the code below (which obviously doesn't work) to make it easier to understand what I want to achieve.

```
if (document.hasFocus()) ≥ 15 {
    do something
}
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you just want to count for 15 times before calling some function or executing some logic, the variable that is responsible for counting represents your application state. So we will call it `count`

```js
let count = 0;
```

then we just increment count while the condition is met every second, until finally we stop the interval when the condition is met

```js
let intervalToken = setInterval(function checkDocument(){

   if(document.hasFocus()){
     count = count + 1;

     if(count > 15){
         clearInterval(intervalToken); // stop intervale here
         callMyFunction();  // call your function here
      }

   }

}, 1000)
```

Comment: I realized now that what I really needed was just the "===" operator. ">=" or ">" performs the function every second (based on interval time). I adapted that and it worked as it should. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

document.hasFocus() returns a boolean not a number.
So you can use a counter and increment it each time document.hasFocus() returns true.
Then you can test the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a counter like this:

```
let counter = 0;
if (document.hasFocus() && ++counter >= 15) {
    alert('you did it!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a variable to count the number of times `document.hasFocus()`.

```js
let focusCount = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  focusCount = document.hasFocus() ? focusCount + 1 : focusCount;
  if (focusCount >= 15) {
    console.log(focusCount);
  }
}, 1000);
```